# Reverse association and map through its values/keys

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, associations

I suspect this could be done in a shorter and more readable code:

Challenge: do it without `Normal` and `Association`.

```
Clear[asoc, a, b, c, d, e, f]

asoc = <|{a, b} -> {1, 4}, {c, d} -> {2, 5}, {e, f} -> {3, 6}|>

(fu |-> fu -> #[[2]]) /@ #[[1]] & /@ 
  List @@@ Reverse /@ Normal@asoc // Association

Map[fu |-> fu -> #[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ 
  List @@@ Reverse /@ Normal@asoc // Association
```

---

```
<|{a, b} -> {1, 4}, {c, d} -> {2, 5}, {e, f} -> {3, 6}|>

<|1 -> {a, b}, 4 -> {a, b}, 2 -> {c, d}, 5 -> {c, d}, 3 -> {e, f}, 6 -> {e, f}|>

<|1 -> {a, b}, 4 -> {a, b}, 2 -> {c, d}, 5 -> {c, d}, 3 -> {e, f}, 6 -> {e, f}|>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
AssociationMap[Thread[#, List, 1] & @* Reverse] @ asoc
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {a, b}, 4 -> {a, b}, 2 -> {c, d}, 5 -> {c, d},   
>   3 -> {e, f}, 6 -> {e, f}|>
> ```

Comment: Never ever I have used `AssociationMap` that is maybe why my code is cumbersome :-)

Answer (score 6):

Without using `Normal` and only using `Association` in disguise:

```
<| KeyValueMap[{k, v} |-> Map[# -> k &, v], asoc] |>
```

> ```
> <| 1->{a,b}, 4->{a,b}, 2->{c,d}, 5->{c,d}, 3->{e,f}, 6->{e,f} |>
> ```